# How to check if a parent SCNNode contains a child SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scnnode

In UIKit I can check if a view is a subView of another view:

```
if !childView.isDescendant(of: parentView) {

    parentView.addSubview(childView)

} else {

    childView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

For a SCNNode what's the equivalent of `.isDescendant(of: )` so I can I do the same thing with a SCNNode:

```
if !childNode.???(of: parentNode) {

    parentNode.addChildNode(childNode)

} else {

    childNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `childNodes.contains()` and you use it like:

```
if !parentNode.childNodes.contains(yourChildNode) {

    parentNode.addChildNode(yourChildNode)

} else {

    yourChildNode.removeFromParentNode()
}
```

[image]

[image]